# Dynamic content in admin panel

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am currently building an admin control panel for a site me and some buddies are launching. I would like for the panel to contain a menu on the left that just switches out what content is displayed on the main page in the center right. So basically the menu is composed of buttons and when a button is clicked I want it to change what content is visible. Is this possible with javascript? And if so, does anyone know how to link it in to the html? Do i give the tags some sort of identifier that a javascript function calls? I know my question might seem a big vague, but any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you want to use one of three options to get these results: 1) frames, 2) iframes, 3) ajax. JavaScript would be involved in all three instances. Which of the three would you want to use?

Comment: @James You could also do it by simply hiding and revealing the correct divs in a parent container div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery. It would be something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPage(thePage) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: thePage,
                success: function(response) {
                     $('#main_content').html(response);
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // I just imagine you have some php pages here
            $('#add_employee').click = loadPage('AddEmployee.php');
            $('#show_employee').click = loadPage('ShowEmployees.php');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left_panel">
        <a href="#" id="add_employee">Add employee</a>
        <a href="#" id="show_employee">Show employees</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main_content">
        // This is your main content on the right of the admin panel
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like simpleTabs and Jquery. I have created a demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/6kN5M/

Basically ignore the CSS layout if you want. The main thing to understand from the markup is that the first tab/button is highlighted and it shows the first piece of content. When you lick on another tab/button this shows the other piece of content. You can add as many tabs as you like.